# Babel ES6 Modules: Why is babel renaming imports

Tags: ecmascript-6, babeljs

When running babel over my ES6 imports it renames my imports all the way through my source:

```
import {foo as bar} from './bar';
console.log(bar);
```

becomes

```
'use strict';
var _bar = require('./bar');
console.log(_bar.foo);
```

A named import is renamed from:

```
import {bar} from './bar';
console.log(bar);
```

to

```
'use strict';
var _bar = require('./bar');
console.log(_bar.bar);
```

And it is even worse with default imports, since a 2 is also added:

```
import bar from './bar';
console.log(bar);
```

becomes

```
'use strict';
function _interopRequireDefault(obj) { return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj : { 'default': obj }; }
var _bar = require('./bar');
var _bar2 = _interopRequireDefault(_bar);
console.log(_bar2['default']);
```

Why is babel doing this? Background: When debugging an application in Chrome, I need to go to the source file to find out how the variable has been renamed to get its current value since Chrome does not know that `bar` has been renamed to `_bar.bar` ... It makes debugging with tools like WebStorm almost impossible ...

Why can't babel transform the named import to

```
'use strict';
var _bar = require('./bar');
var bar = _bar.bar;
console.log(bar);
```

and the default import to

```
'use strict';
function _interopRequireDefault(obj) { return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj : { 'default': obj }; }
var _bar = require('./bar');
var _bar2 = _interopRequireDefault(_bar);
var bar = _bar2['default']
console.log(bar);
```

Comment: I can't answer the *why*, but you should be generating [sourcemaps](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-babel#source-maps) in order to debug or you're going to have much harder problems debugging that finding the name of modules.

Comment: I am generating sourcemaps, but as far as I know, the Chrome Inspector is not aware of sourcemaps and can't detect variable renaming ... Also the debugger is "jumping" to the right source file but cannot inspect variables.

Comment: "*Why can't babel transform …*" - it surely can, it's just not what they did do. I don't think there are any good reasons for choosing one over the other, except for debuggability, as they are evaluated equivalently. You might want to open a bug (feature request?) if you care about this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is done to simulate "reference" nature of module imports. In

```
import {foo as bar} from './bar';
console.log(bar);
```

`bar` is not just a variable that holds a value, it's a *reference* to the export from the other module. If the exported values changes, so will the import.

Example:

```
// a.js
export var a = 42;
setTimeout(() => a = 21, 500);

// b.js
import {a} from './a';
setTimeout(() => console.log(a), 1000);
```

According to the spec, the code in `b.js` has to log `21`. Since JavaScript doesn't have *assign-by-reference*, the only way to achieve such a behavior is to convert every import to a MemberExpression (`foo.bar`).